# Find OS type from .Net CF 1.0

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

What is the API for getting the OS type? Windows CE or Windows mobile?

```
Environment.OSVersion
```

just gives the CE version. It does not provide information if 'Windows Mobile' is installed on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these blog articles on Platform detection:

- [Platform Detection I](https://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/09/15/756755.aspx)
- [Platform Detection II](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/09/22/766343.aspx)

Comment: Archive.org links: https://web.archive.org/web/20100107164917/https://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/09/15/756755.aspx

Comment: Archive.org link: https://web.archive.org/web/20081221202747/http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/09/22/766343.aspx